# Get UIImage as it appears in the UIImageView after UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill is applied

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I was wondering if its possible to take an image exactly as it appears after `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` has been applied to the image's `UIImageView`, and save that scaled image as a new image to be modified upon?  For example, if I just do the following:

```
UIImageView *addToView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:testImage];
NSLog(@"testImage size %f, %f", testImage.size.width, testImage.size.height);
addToView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
NSLog(@"testImage size %f, %f", testImage.size.width, testImage.size.height); //the reported size is still the same
```

.. the size report is still the same.

My goal for this is to take an `UIImage` at its original size, rescale it based on a fixed size (hence using the included `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` to help me) , and then combine it with another `UIImage` to produce a third image.  I have tried using 3rd party libraries to rescale my image as using [NYXImageKit](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit) or [MGImageUtilities](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities), but have found the results currently unsatisfactory as it does not "clip to bounds" (and there is no way to set the `UIImage` to clip to bounds, rather than the `UIImageView`), as well as produce an image that is not at the @2x resolution for retina displays.